# Creating Daily In-Use table w/ Zeros When NULL

Tags: sql, create-table, days

Hello Stack Community,

I am not sure if I titled this accurately, but I am attempting to create a table that tracks the daily in-use quantity by product code. Currently my code drops dates where a product isn't in-use whereas I need that to show as a 0.

My thoughts where that by using the date from the date table that my LEFT OUTER JOIN with the ISNULL on the field would produce a 0, but nay.

Here is my code, with a screenshot of what it outputs with the red square highlighting where it's missing date records that I need to show as 0 :

```
SELECT  
DD.DATE,
DE.PRODUCT_CODE,
--OOC = OUT OF CONTEXT, EITHER ISN'T CHARGEABLE OR ISN'T CURRENTLY ACTIVE
ISNULL(SUM(LIDV.QTY - LIDV.QTYSUB),0),
OD.LOCATION,
OD.SOURCE
FROM Dim_Date AS DD
LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDERv_DatesDays AS OD ON DD.DATE BETWEEN OD.SHIP_DATE AND OD.adjRETURN_DATE
LEFT OUTER JOIN FACT_Orders_LIDs AS LIDV ON LIDV.SORDERID_DAX = OD.SORDERID_DAX
LEFT OUTER JOIN DIM_ECODES AS DE ON DE.PRODUCT_CODE = LIDV.eCODE
WHERE 
--DD.DATE = '3/1/2017' AND
DD.DATE BETWEEN '1/1/2017' AND EOMONTH( DATEADD( MONTH , -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) AND 
DE.PRODUCT_CODE = '07316-' AND 
YEAR(DD.DATE) = 2017
GROUP BY 
DD.DATE,
DE.PRODUCT_CODE,
OD.LOCATION,
OD.SOURCE
ORDER BY
DD.DATE
```

[image: missing dates in red square]

I also thought, since I'm no SQL expert, that perhaps I need to just create a table with each product code and date for a specified date range but I got tripped up trying to create that as well.

Thank you for any assistance, if I need to add more info just let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: I recommend you use dates in a format of '2000-12-31' in your hard coded string constants, by the way

Comment: Why does the query in the screenshot and the query in the question differ?

Comment: It's not, it's the same just w/out the 'create table' section and the final order by clause.

Comment: And the where clause is different.. So then the question is "to which one of these different queries does the screenshotted resultsgrid relate?"

Answer (score 0):

This WHERE predicate is killing your left join:

```
DE.PRODUCT_CODE = '07316-' AND
```

If product_code 07316 was not "out on loan" (or whatever) between Feb 24 and April 6 then all those rows *would* have looked like:

```
DATE        PRODUCT_CODE  INUSE LOCATION
2017-02-25  NULL          NULL  NULL
2017-02-26  NULL          NULL  NULL
2017-02-27  NULL          NULL  NULL
2017-02-28  NULL          NULL  NULL
...
2017-04-05  NULL          NULL  NULL
```

But, that NULL in `product_code` means that when the where clause asks "is NULL equal to 07316- ?" the answer is *false*, so the row diasppears from the resultset

---

Consider

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN DIM_ECODES AS DE 
ON 
  DE.PRODUCT_CODE = LIDV.eCODE AND 
  DE.PRODUCT_CODE = '07316-'
```

You might also want to make some changes in the SELECT block too:

```
'07316-' as PRODUCT_CODE,
COALESCE(INUSE,0) AS INUSE
```

---

It might make more sense to you to write it like this:

```
FROM 
  Dim_Date AS DD
  LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  (
    SELECT 
      OD.SHIP_DATE, 
      OD.adjRETURN_DATE,
      LIDV.QTY,
      LIDV.QTYSUB,
      OD.LOCATION,
      OD.SOURCE
    FROM
      ORDERv_DatesDays AS OD 
      INNER JOIN FACT_Orders_LIDs AS LIDV ON LIDV.SORDERID_DAX = OD.SORDERID_DAX
      INNER JOIN DIM_ECODES AS DE ON DE.PRODUCT_CODE = LIDV.eCODE
    WHERE
      DE.PRODUCT_CODE = '07316-'
  ) x
  ON DD.DATE BETWEEN x.SHIP_DATE AND x.adjRETURN_DATE

WHERE
```

This is "list of dates on the left" and "any relevant data, already joined together and where'd on the right"

It should also be noted that if you're doing this for multiple product codes, to prevent just a single date row if both product 07316 and 07317 are in use on the 28th Feb you'd need to:

```
FROM 
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT DD.DATE, DE.PRODUCT_CODE 
    FROM Dim_Date AS DD CROSS JOIN DIM_ECODES DE
    WHERE ..date range clause..
  )
```

This takes your list of dates, and crosses it with your list of prod codes, so you can be certain there are at least these two rows:

```
2017-02-28 07316-
2017-02-28 07317-
```

Then when you left join the products on date and product code, both those rows' data survive the left join, and become associated with nulls:

```
2017-02-28 07316- NULL NULL 
2017-02-28 07317- NULL NULL
```

Without doing that CROSS, you'd have just one row (null in product code)

Comment: I am specifically using that product code (of over 300k codes) so I have a small sample set while I work on my code, my entire table is several hundred million rows. The results are the same whether I filter by that code in the WHERE clause or not.

Comment: Provided that those rows truly are in the dates table, then those rows are represented *somewhere* but they don't have a product code of 07316, so you can't find them that way. If you run the query without the product code being present  and get your `several hundred million rows` * `your number of date rows` (i.e. billions of rows,) you'll still only find them once in the resultset if no product has been "in use" on those dates

Comment: Your technique for "I want all 365 dates in 2017, plus only those days where products match" is sound (`dates LEFT JOIN products WHERE date in 2017`), but mentioning in a WHERE clause *any* table that is on the right hand side of "left join" will convert the join to an inner (effectively) because all the nulls the LEFT introduces are removed by the WHERE. Any one of your other joins can fail and the dates will be retained.. unless theyre then filtered out subsequently

Comment: Yes, the missing dates are on the dates' table but as you correctly presumed I have no in-use data for the product code for some dates which is why I'm trying to represent a 0 for those non-in use dates (if that makes sense). 

The several hundred million rows comment is the table with all of our product codes, just missing dates like those in the screenshot. It wouldn't be billions after. 

Didn't know that on the left join and RIGHT table where clause, THANK YOU!

Comment: Added another note about if youre doing this for multiple products; it could be important for you to consider